# Start batch > start exe + stop exe > batch activation

Tags: batch-file

Batch:

```
@echo off
tasklist /FI "IMAGENAME eq custom.bin" 2>NUL | find /I /N "custom.bin">NUL
if "%ERRORLEVEL%"=="0" goto mycode
goto quite
:mycode
@RD /S /Q "customfolder"
:quite
exit
```

now I need to make it work as in the header, step by step:

1. Run batch
2. Run custom.bin
3. Close custom.bin
4. And now our batch understand that we ve closed custom.bin and
   execute custom folder and custom files deletion. Can someone give a
   hand? Is it even possible that kind of stuff?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you're trying to do something like this:

```
@echo off
start /wait custom.bin
echo custom.bin has finished running
pause
```

This starts custom.bin, and waits until it closes, and after that continues to run the rest of the batch-file